# Submit form on enter press

Tags: javascript

Rookie question. I have a simple form with an input box and a submit button. When the button is clicked it triggers some php to search for the input term & output any results. I want to be able to press enter after typing my search term, rather than having to click the button.

I'm aware this is a basic thing and I've found solutions on here but when I've tried to add a keyup event listener to my code it doesn't seem to change anything and I'm not clear why - with or without the js pressing enter seems to refresh the page? I'm guessing that the problem is I don't want to "submit" the form, I want to do something else?

Here is the code:

```
<?php  
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
*Removed the search php because I assume it is not relevant to the question*
?>

<div class="site-section bg-dark" id="start">
  <div style="padding-left: 20px">
    <h3 class="text-white">Find book based on title</h3>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class=" mb-4">

        <div class="form-group">
          <form method="post">
            <label for="title">Title</label>
            <input type="text" id="title" name="title" class="form-control" placeholder="Title">
            <p></p>
            <button class="btn m-1 btn-secondary">
              <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="View Results">
            </button>
          </form>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    
  <script>
    var input = document.getElementById("title");
    input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
      event.preventDefault();
      document.getElementById("submit").click();
    }
    });
  </script>

  *Results output here*
</div>
```

Many thanks.

**Edit:**
Resolved, thanks for the suggestions. It turned out that this was only a problem in Firefox, not Chrome, and the reason was this:

```
        <button class="btn m-1 btn-secondary">
          <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="View Results">
        </button>
```

input type="submit" is already a button, and wrapping it around another button apparently caused the browser some confusion.

Comment: You don't have to do anything for this. That's the default functionality of forms having a submit button. *"The submit event fires when the user clicks a submit button (`<button>` or `<input type="submit">`) or presses Enter while editing a field (e.g. `<input type="text">`) in a form. "* https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit_event

Comment: add type="submit" on button.

Comment: @Shashank — There's no point in doing that, that's the default.

Comment: Also don't nest buttons.

Comment: "I'm guessing that the problem is I don't want to "submit" the form, I want to do something else?" — Then add a submit event handler that prevents the default behaviour. Don't try to have specific behaviour for the enter key.

Comment: If your form only has 1 field, that is the default feature, no need to code.

Comment: Thanks all for the comments but as I mentioned above, when I press enter the page just refreshes. I don't want it to do that - I want it to execute the php, which is what it does when I click the submit button.

Comment: @Charlie Could you add the other code or provide a JSFiddle link with all the code?  It seems to work OK for me regardless of the button click or enter press.

Comment: @ollie that's interesting. The website is here:http://theantilibrary.co.uk/db/read2.php

Comment: Have you tried using an `iframe` and then using `target=""` in your input tags?

Comment: Thanks for your help @Ollie. I've managed to resolve the problem now.